# Vuex getters return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Here's my `store.js` code :

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        staffID: '',
        count: 0,
    },
    getters:{
        getStaffID: state => {
            console.log("13 getStaffID: " + state.staffID)
            return state.staffID;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        UPDATE_STAFFID: (state,value) => {
            state.staffID = value
            console.log("20 mutations: " + state.staffID)
        },
    },
    actions: {
        update_staffID: (context, payload) => {
            context.commit("UPDATE_STAFFID", payload)
        }
    }
  })
```

And in my component, there's a button which will call this:

```
this.$store.commit('UPDATE_STAFFID','miow')
console.log("store.getStaffID: " + this.$store.getStaffID);
console.log("store.staffID: " + this.$store.staffID);
```

The resulting log will display this:

```
20 mutations: miow
13 getStaffID: miow
store.getStaffID: undefined
store.staffID: undefined
```

This is very confusing for me. From the log, I can conclude that:

- mutation UPDATE_STAFFID runs OK
- `state.staffID` inside getStaffID getter in store.js will output the desired value which is `miow`
- but the return value from the getter above will somehow return `undefined`
- trying to access the staffID value directly using `this.$store.staffID` will also return undefined

Why those `undefined`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `getters` and `state` properties so add them like :

```
 console.log("store.getStaffID: " + this.$store.getters.getStaffID);
 console.log("store.staffID: " + this.$store.state.staffID);
```

Comment: actually I have to do `console.log("store.getStaffID: " + this.$store.getters.getStaffID);` to get the value. if I add () at the end of getStaffID it will return `Uncaught TypeError: this.$store.getters.getStaffID is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, i fixed that